# Look up field not getting updated

Tags: lookup

I experienced this issue sometime back and do not remember a fix for it..I am trying to update a look up field for an object on a custom object.
When i try to save it, the history says shows that it is updating to the desired value but reverting back the changes after the initial update.
I tried updating other fields and it has no problem..

There are no triggers/processbuilder flows which are restricting this update as far as i could explore. This has left me puzzled..Have you guys experienced this?

Comment: are you sure there are no triggers/handler classes or workflows/process flows?  Does the reversion happen in the same transaction (or at a later time)?

Comment: There are none which are restricting the update. It seems to happen in the same transaction.When i enable field tracking on that field, i see that it is getting updated to the desired value and then going back to the original value  immediately.

Comment: i've seen this before with opportunity closedate vs currentDate but not on custom objects. Try creating a custom object Foo with a lookup to the same object you are having trouble with to see if that provides a clue

Comment: The lookup field is Account and it has many references. This same update works in production though :(